# No eligible bundle identifiers submission error

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, iad

I just went to submit my first app involving iAds, and in the beginning of the app submissions process there is a new button to "Enable iAds". I click and get the following error:

"You have no eligible bundle identifiers. Please register one here."

So i went to my provisioning portal, expecting to see a configure iAds option similar to GameKit, in app purchase, etc; but no dice. What gives?

Btw, my iAds network contract is in place with the nice green checkmark of completitude. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a unique App Id in this case to add iAd functionality, like com.yourcompany.yourappname in the dev provisioning centre. Look up creating unique App Id there are many resources. This will give you the necessary bundle identifier.

Comment: Thanks; I actually just got this working on my own too.  What was confusing to me is that for some reason the existing unique App Ids in my provisioning portal (even ones for apps i haven't submitted yet) were not selectable... That's kind of a bug isn't it?

Comment: @Niell: I'm not sure about that. Read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your AppID is not using a wild-card bundle. While the provisioning portal does not mention iAds explicitly, it does mention that wild-card App IDs can't be used for push notifications or in-app purchases, and I do have the sneaking suspicion the same limitation applies to the iAd network as well.

Comment: Thanks I got it working.  The odd thing is that I did have several existing unique IDs...see my note to Neill below; every strange.

Comment: You are certainly right about the push notification and in-app purchases, but iAd is either weird or there's some sort of bug, or I'm doing something wrong. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I' having the same issue with a new app I'm trying to upload today. But here are my inputs:

1 - I have a family suite of apps (about 48) called "You Know You Are" (ie: You know You Are a Guy, You Know You Are from Miami, etc). Each have their own unique appID. Out of those 48 only ONE of those appear in ENABLE iAD section.

2 - I have another set of app call "How Long Can You" (ie: How Long Can You Tap It and How Long Can You Turn It). I never created a unique appID for these. The app bundle DOES have each of them unique(com.site.tapit, com.site.turnit) and the Distribution profile I sign it with with the wildcard profile. When I went to update those apps yesterday, they DID show up. No typo here, I double checked, YES I did say that I WAS able to enable iAd for those two apps.

I was reading a bit on why only one my other family apps appear in the list. I came across this thread and decided to add my 2-cents, more like 1-and-a-half-cents since I feel none of this makes sense ;)

Also, I decided to follow instructions and I just added a new AppID for a new app I want to upload and I still do not see it in the list.

Hope this sheds some light to help fix/diagnose what is going on.