# How to solve "no eligible Bundle IDs for iOS apps"?

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

I just went to submit my first app that uses iAds, and got the following error:

> You have no eligible Bundle IDs for iOS apps. Register one here.

My App ID is green in App Push Notification, In-App Purchase, and Game Center.

What does this mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No eligible bundle identifiers submission error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145835/no-eligible-bundle-identifiers-submission-error)

Answer (score 0):

Have you accepted the appropriate contract, set up bank account info, etc. in iTunesConnect?